# List Item is being replaced by a header on recyclerview using multiple viewtype

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using `RecyclerView` and I want to include a Header text above my Recyclerview items which I created using multiple viewType. Image below is the result. Works fine but it seems like the header `I'm header` replaces the first item from my Sample Text list items. It should be Sample Text 1 until 10 being displayed on the list. So there should be `Sample Text 1` displaying on the result which is missing from the output image below.

[image: Multiple View Types]

Below is the code for `MyAdapter.class`

```
  public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private List<Sample> sampleList;
private Context mContext;

private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;

private Header header;

public MyAdapter (Header head, List<Sample> list) {
    header = head;
    sampleList= list;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    mContext = parent.getContext();
    View view;

    if(viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_header, parent, false);
        return new HeaderHolder(view);
    } else if(viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_main, parent, false);
        return new ItemHolder(view);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if(holder instanceof HeaderHolder) {

        HeaderHolder VHheader = (HeaderHolder)holder;
        VHheader.txtTitle.setText(header.getHeader());

    } else if(holder instanceof ItemHolder) {
        ((ItemHolder) holder).sample.setText("Sample Text "+ position );
   }
}

@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return sampleList.size()+1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(isPositionHeader(position))
            return TYPE_HEADER;
        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    private boolean isPositionHeader(int position)
    {
        return position == 0;
    }
  private class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView sample;

    ItemHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
      sample= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sampleText);
 }

 private class HeaderHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView txtTitle;
    HeaderHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.txtTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtHeader);
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to add dummy item at your list 0th position. all your problem will be solved

Comment: @jiteshmohite how can i do that

Comment: In else part of your onBindViewHolder use position-1 instead of position.

Comment: Because when position = 0, holder will be instance of HeaderHolder and for position > 0, holder will be instance of ItemHolder, therefore you are skipping 0 position of your list.

Comment: Okay Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use position-1 instead of position because when position = 0, holder will be instance of HeaderHolder and for position > 0, holder will be instance of ItemHolder, therefore you are skipping 0 position of your list.

Use below code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if(holder instanceof HeaderHolder) {

        HeaderHolder VHheader = (HeaderHolder)holder;
        VHheader.txtTitle.setText(header.getHeader());

    } else if(holder instanceof ItemHolder) {
        ((ItemHolder) holder).sample.setText("Sample Text "+ (position-1) );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code inside adapter

```
public MyAdapter (Header head, List<Sample> list) {
    header = head;
    sampleList= list;
    sampleList.add(0, new Sample()) // added dummy element in 0th position
}
```

As 0th position is used to set for your header. Recycler view doesn't provide any approach in which we can manage list for multiple view type.
Hope these help you.