# Facing the missing element issue in Multi view type in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, multiview

I'm trying to achieve like this [Two recyclerview when i scroll down , the first recylcer to be scrolled too, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45688512/two-recyclerview-when-i-scroll-down-the-first-recylcer-to-be-scrolled-too-how/45688735#45688735)

I implemented this but I'm facing issue like 0th element of second list in second view type is missing but when I post new item then that missing item visible at position 1 of adapter but then that new item in second list is missing until and unless I don't post any any item in second list

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (isPositionPopularRt(position)) {
        return TYPE_POPULAR_RT;
    }
    return TYPE_POST_LIST;
}

private boolean isPositionPopularRt(int position) {
    return position == 0;
}
@NotNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NotNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    mUserModel = SharedPrefsUtils.getObject(AppConstants.PrefKey.KEY_USER_MODEL, UserModel.class);
    if (viewType == TYPE_POST_LIST) {
        //inflate your layout and pass it to view holder
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_for_cell, viewGroup, false);
        CustomViewHolder tempViewHolder = new CustomViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(tempViewHolder);
        return tempViewHolder;
    } else if (viewType == TYPE_POPULAR_RT) {
        //inflate your layout and pass it to view holder
        View v =  LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.popular_rt_recycler_view, viewGroup, false);
        return new MyViewHolderPopularRt(v);
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("there is no type that matches the type " + viewType + " + make sure your using types correctly");
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on the issue? Not able to understand the problem statement here.

Comment: @JeelVankhede refer the ss in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42219507/list-item-is-being-replaced-by-a-header-on-recyclerview-using-multiple-viewtype  im facing same issue just like this question

Comment: @JeelVankhede i followed the solution in above link but is there any other solution for it why first item of list is not visble?

Comment: Either you'll need to add popular_rt type to your post list at item level zero or else let adapter know total how many items you need to render. Because, when you provide list items to your adapter you only tell to render list items and not popular_rt.